# Rope as strong as 3/16" steel rope?

Tags: fence

We'll be using this to cordon an area, and we were initially thinking of using 3/16"wire rope. It'll be tight enough so that it's straight, but that's pretty much it.

But then we thought that rope looks slightly nicer, so I'm thinking what type of rope is as strong and doesn't stretch at all regardless of the climate?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's just to cordon off an area, what strength do you really need?

Comment: Ropes which don't stretch are called "static rope," as opposed to dynamic.

Comment: [AMSTEEL®](http://www.samsonrope.com/Pages/Product.aspx?ProductID=872) is supposedly as strong as steel, but I've never tested it to the breaking point.  It's used in the off-road world as winch cable, because it's strong and doesn't weigh much.

Answer (score 2):

If low stretch is your objective, a good choice is Spectra™ brand material. It is frequently used with an over-braid cover material to reduce abrasion and contact damage. Spectra™ is used inside support lines for paraglider canopies, as a bit of stretch creates inaccurate lofting of the canopy and control complications. That Spectra™ is typically 1 mm in diameter with an extremely high breaking strength.

You can find 3/16" diameter Spectra™ online and in many local marine or climbing shops. It comes in various colors of over-braid, allowing for better visibility than the natural (whitish) color of the raw material.

The level of stretch is minimal and once tensioned, is likely to stay taut. It is not affected by moisture, but can be damaged by sunlight and UV and may change tension slightly with extreme temperature changes.

As shown on [one web site](https://www.machovec.com/rope/spectra_double_braid.htm), the breaking strength of 3/16" double braided Spectra™ is 1956 pounds/884 kilograms, certainly strong enough to contain unruly crowds.

It is also relatively attractive if your color selection is done carefully.

[image: spectra double braided line]